# How to access the function "foo" via the string "foo" in NodeJS?

Tags: module, node.js, window, export

i.e. what's the equivalent of the browser's "window" object, to which top level functions are attached?

The following code succeeds in the REPL:

```
var assert = require('assert');
function foo() { };
assert.ok(foo == this["foo"]);
```

However in a script (or a module) it fails--in both cases "this" is an empty object.

I'm wondering about this so I can easily export all functions visible in a module's namespace--I want to be able to do something like:

```
function foo() { };
function bar() { };

["foo", "bar"].forEach(function (k) {
    exports[k] = ???;
});
```

(`eval(k)` works for the ???, but, ugh.)

Comment: The best I could figure out is to export the function when you define it: `var foo = exports.foo = function(){...};`. Or, you could create your own object containing the functions you'll later export: `var fns = {}; fns.foo = function(){...}; ... fns.forEach(...);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matt Ball's answer is pretty good:

```
var foo = exports.foo = function() {
  //...
};. 

// Or, you could create your own object containing 
// the functions you'll later export: 

var fns = {}; 

fns.foo = function(){...}; 

// ... 

fns.forEach(/*...*/); 

// – Matt Ball Feb 27 at 14:42
```

Alternatively,

```
exports.foo = {
  method1: function() { /*...*/ }
, method2: function() { /*...*/ }
, method3: function() { /*...*/ }
  /*...*/
}
```

Some modules which exhibit best practices:
https://github.com/cloudhead/journey/blob/master/lib/journey.js
For browser compat: https://github.com/caolan/async/blob/master/lib/async.js
https://github.com/mikeal/request/blob/master/main.js

/fyi #node.js IRC welcomes you: http://bit.ly/nodeIRC